# ¿Cómo insertar varias gráficas de Google Charts en la misma página?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Estoy intentando mostrar varias gráficas en una misma página en mi web con la API de Google Charts. Con las gráficas que yo creo con los datos en el propio script no hay problemas, tengo 3 y todas funcionan a la vez. Pero tengo otras 2 que leen los datos de una hoja de google spreadsheets y estas no funcionan a la vez o va una o la otra pero nunca las dos a la vez. Independientes funcionan ambas.

El otro problema es que solo consigo leer los datos en la hoja 1, si creo una hoja 2 para otra tabla me sigue leyendo los de la hoja 1.

Así lo tengo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FR6MtaelC0bc8GPijnmhglgNNIQgJQbtyKtv7DstVvSl5Wyvg/edit#gid=0');
        query.setQuery('SELECT A, H, I');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
  }


  var options = {
              title: 'grafica 1 ejemplo',
              bars: 'vertical',
              vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
              height: 500,
              backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
              fontName: 'Roboto',
              colors: ['#1b9e77', '#ee6e73']
          };

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('grafica1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FR6MtaelC0bc8GPijnmhglgNNIQgJQbtyKtv7DstVvSl5Wyvg/edit#gid=2004428288');
    query.setQuery('SELECT A, B');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
          var options = {
              title: 'grafica 2 ejemplo',
              bars: 'vertical',
              vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
              height: 500,
              backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
              fontName: 'Roboto',
              colors: ['#ff5722']
          };
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('grafica2'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>

<div id="grafica1"></div><br>

<div id="grafica2"></div><br>
```

Comment: cuando publicas una pregunta puedes utilizar fragmento js/html/css para ejecutar tu código y poder verlo, asi seria mucho mejor

Comment: Ok, así lo haré. Gracias

Comment: Utilizas el mismo nombre de función, `drawChart()` dos veces. Me parece que la solución mínima podría ser cambiar el nombre en una de ellas.

Comment: He probado ha cambiar el nombre a la función y tampoco funciona. Las otras 3 tienen el mismo nombre la función y se visualizan las gráficas sin problemas, solo me pasa con las que me leen datos de la tabla alojada en spreadsheets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que en tu código marca una excepción, además como menciona Rubén la función  `drawChart()` esta dos veces

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
 var query;
 query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_XBM9KywYorDx0UMRMnNP_YS-sho-YTY5QNJQywFIJw/edit?usp=sharing');
 query.setQuery('SELECT A, H, I');
 query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
 if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }


 var options = {
                  title: 'grafica 1 ejemplo',
                  bars: 'vertical',
                  vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
                  height: 500,
                  backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
                  fontName: 'Roboto',
                  colors: ['#1b9e77', '#ee6e73']
              };

 var data = response.getDataTable();

 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('grafica1'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart2() {
 var query2;
 query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_XBM9KywYorDx0UMRMnNP_YS-sho-YTY5QNJQywFIJw/edit?usp=sharing');
 query2.setQuery('SELECT A, B');
 query2.send(handleQueryResponse2);
}

function handleQueryResponse2(response) {
              var options = {
                  title: 'grafica 2 ejemplo',
                  bars: 'vertical',
                  vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
                  height: 500,
                  backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
                  fontName: 'Roboto',
                  colors: ['#ff5722']
              };
      var data = response.getDataTable();
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('grafica2'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

setTimeout(function(){
 drawChart();
 drawChart2();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="grafica1"></div><br>
<div id="grafica2"></div><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

En este código le doy un timeout para que cargue la librería de google, habría que investigar si existe un callback cuando se cargue jsapi

Comment: Pues si, funciona perfectamente. Había probado de varias formas pero de manera incorrecta. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Por cierto, es verdad que sin el timeout no funciona, imagino que igual hay alguna manera al modo de jquery "$(document).ready(function($)..."